# In Spring MVC custom JSP tag: "Cannot find symbol": pageContext

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Why would the `pageContext` variable not be findable in this custom tag installed in the `WEB-INF/tags` directory of a Spring MVC app?

```
<%@ tag import="com.ocpsoft.pretty.time.PrettyTime, java.util.Date"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="dateParam" required="true" type="java.util.Date" %>

<%
 PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
 String prettyDate = p.format(dateParam);
 pageContext.setAttribute("prettyDate", prettyDate);
%>
<c:out value="${prettyDate}"/>
```

The error is:

```
cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable pageContext
```

I thought this was an implicit variable that should be available by default.

Comment: Are you getting this error by IDE's suggestion ? or when you compile ?

Comment: Both from IDE and compilation process.

Comment: Are JSP and JSTL JAR file in your classpath ?

Comment: Yes both jars are in the classpath. And this is a sizeable Spring MVC web app that already has numerous JSPs with JSTL. But this is the first custom tag I've created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In tag files you should use `jspContext` instead of `pageContext`.

**See also:**

- [JSP 2.1 Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html), section JSP.8.8.